# How to fix "the trait Factory<_, _, _> is not implemented for {function}" error in actix_web?

Tags: rust, serde, actix-web

I have this simple code:

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{json};
use validator::{Validate, ValidationError};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Validate)]
struct Auth {
    #[validate(length(min = 4))]
    username: String,
    password: String,
}

#[post("/auth")]
async fn auth(form: web::Json<Auth>) -> Result<serde_json::Value, ValidationError> {
    Ok(json!{ "success" })
}
```

This keeps giving me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(Json<Auth>) -> impl std::future::Future {auth}: Factory<_, _, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:77:10
   |
77 | async fn auth(form: web::Json<Auth>) -> Result<serde_json::Value, ValidationError> {
   |          ^^^^ the trait `Factory<_, _, _>` is not implemented for `fn(Json<Auth>) -> impl std::future::Future {auth}`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Changing `Result<serde_json::Value, ValidationError>` to `HttpResponse` and returning the json in `HttpResponse` worked.

```
#[post("/auth")]
async fn auth(form: web::Json<Auth>) -> HttpResponse {
    match form.validate() {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(json!{ {"success":true}}),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::NotAcceptable().body(format!("{}", e))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With my case, I had forgotten to import the `post` macro from `actix_web`.